# Characteristic equation of the transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> (a) Write down the characteristic equations for the PDE
>   $$u_t+b\cdot Du =f \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$$
>   where $b\in \mathbb{R}^n, f=f(x,t)$.
>
> (b) Use the characteristic ODE to solve the equation above subject to the initial condition
>   $$u=g \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^n\times \{t=0\}$$

What I have done:

Let $B=(1,b)$ then the equation have the following fashion
$$F(p,z,x)=B\cdot p-f$$
therefore 
$$D_pF=B=x(s)$$
$$D_pF\cdot p=B\cdot p=f =z(s)$$

We got the equations

$$\begin{Bmatrix} \dot x(s)=B  \\ \dot z(s)=f \\ \dot p= D_x f \end{Bmatrix}$$

In this case $x=(x^1,...,x^n,t)$. This solve (a). Am I right?

For (b) we solve the differential equation of before:

$$x(s)=Bs+C$$
$$z(s)=\int f(s)ds $$

But I do not know how to continue from here. Somebody can explain me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is linear equation, you don't really need to introduce the variable $p$. Use the first two equations and separate the $t$ variable from them:
$$\begin{Bmatrix} \dot t(s)=1\\ \dot x(s)=b  \\ \dot z(s)=f  \end{Bmatrix}$$
The $x,t$ are easy to solve:
$$t(s)=s+c_1\\
x(s)=bs+c_2$$
The initial values are
$$t(0)=0\\x(0)=x_0\\z(0)=g(x_0)$$

Eliminate $s$ and incorporate the initial condition:
$$t=s\\x_0=x-bt$$
Now integrate the third equation using the initial value
$$z(x,t)-g(x_0)=\int^t_0f(x(s),s)ds$$

where $x(s)=bs+x_0=bs+x-bt=x+b(s-t)$

You should then be able to get the result.

Comment: Is it not $t$ instead of $s$ in the integral?

Comment: @YotasTrejos: Yes, it should be $t$ after you eliminate $s$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Why do you use twice the $s$ letter?

Comment: And the $r$ in the integral? I think it is $x-bs$? but in the answer say $x+(s-t)b$.

Comment: @YotasTrejos: I used $r,s$ to represent $x,t$ at the beginning. I will edit a little.

Comment: @YotasTrejos: I forgot that $x$ depends on $s$ too. Updated.